# ERROR Error: dataKey must be defined to use row expansion

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to figure out how to use Row Expansion in PrimeEng. I was just following the guide in their documentation and it shows that I should define my datakey. I already defined it below if I'm not mistaken. I'm new to this, please don't judge.

```
<p-table [value]="users" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
    currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50]">
   
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:2rem">blank</th>
        <th style="width:1rem">ID</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">Name</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">Username</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">Email</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">Street</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">Suite</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">City</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">Zip code</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">LAT</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">LNG</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">Phone</th>
        <th style="width:8rem">Website</th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>

<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-user let-expanded="expanded">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- <button type="button" pButton pRipple (click)="viewPostUser(user.id)" class="p-button-text p-button-rounded p-button-plain" ></button> -->
            <button type="button" pButton pRipple [pRowToggler]="posts" (click)="viewPostUser(user.id)" class="p-button-text p-button-rounded p-button-plain" [icon]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'"></button>
        </td>
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td>{{user.address.street}}</td>
        <td>{{user.address.suite}}</td>
        <td>{{user.address.city}}</td>
        <td>{{user.address.zipcode}}</td>
        <td>{{user.address.geo.lat}}</td>
        <td>{{user.address.geo.lng}}</td>
        <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{user.website}}</td>

        
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Here is my row expansion ng-template.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-posts>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <div class="p-p-3">
                <p-table [value]="posts.userId" [dataKey]="posts.userId">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:4rem">userID</th>
                            <th style="width:4rem">ID</th>
                            <th style="width:4rem">Title</th>
                            <th style="width:4rem">Body</th>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-posts>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{posts.userId}}</td>
                            <td>{{posts.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{posts.title}}</td>
                            <td>{{posts.body}}</td>
                            <td><p-button type="button" icon="pi pi-search"></p-button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-table>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

I've tried searching the error that I have, but it points me to updating the version.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is where you get it wrong:

```
[value]="posts.userId" [dataKey]="posts.userId"
```

*[value]* is the collection that you want to iterate through, which should be *posts* in this case
*[dataKey]* is the property of one item in that collection which you could just define by name: *userId*

So the final code is:

```
[value]="posts" [dataKey]="userId"
```

Comment: sadly, it shows that the property "userId" does not exists :< what to dooo?

Comment: then pass the property that exist in your collection, I cannot provide you the precise solution as I don't know your data

Comment: You should either write `[dataKey]="'userId'"` or preferably `dataKey="userId"`, otherwise Angular looks for a member named `userId` on the component.

Comment: @Shai that's what needed, the dataKey is the member, not a string. The dataKey should be a unique value to differentiate between rows.

Comment: It's a string according to the primeNG documentation and also in their examples it is used like this: `<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" dataKey="vin">`. Can also contain a path to an inner member like this: `dataKey="representative.name"`. The string provided to the `dataKey` input tells the p-table which field is the unique key for the table.

Comment: hmm, I just checked the docs and it said the dataKey is a property, even in your example both "vin" and "reps.name" are properties, not random strings.

Answer (score 0):

First, to fix the error you're seeing, add the attribute `dataKey="id"` to the p-table element.

Next, using `let-posts` is probably not what you wanted. You didn't write how your data structure is constructed but I'll assume each user has a property called `posts`. You need to change your template like this:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-user>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <div class="p-p-3">
                <p-table [value]="user.posts" dataKey="id">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:4rem">userID</th>
                            <th style="width:4rem">ID</th>
                            <th style="width:4rem">Title</th>
                            <th style="width:4rem">Body</th>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-post>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{post.userId}}</td>
                            <td>{{post.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{post.title}}</td>
                            <td>{{post.body}}</td>
                            <td><p-button type="button" icon="pi pi-search"></p-button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-table>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Explanation:

1. Use `let-user` in the rowexpansion template. Now the `user` variable will contain the user data for the current expandable row.
2. In the inner `p-table`, provide the `[value]` input with the data for the sub table, i.e., the posts for the current user.
3. In the inner `p-table`, provide the `dataKey` input with the name of the field which is the unique key of the table. This might be even not necessary in your case.
4. In the inner `p-table`, in the body template, use `let-post` instead of `let-posts` since each iteration, i.e., each row of the inner table showing posts for the user, will store the current row, which is a single post.
5. In each `<td>` element in the inner table's body template, use `post.<field-name>`. `post` will contain the data for the current row so all you need to do is access the field you need inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dataKey in first line, like this

```
<p-table [value]="users" dataKey="name">
```

Maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: Format code in your answers using special code forating tool

Answer (score 0):

You should add the dataKey using the property of the object to the first/upper  table ('users' in your case)

```
   <p-table dataKey="id" [value]="users" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
[rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50]">
```

This method worked for me.